# ASUS X200MA US01T White Signature Edition Laptop

Tags: laptop

I just purchased an ASUS X200MA US01T White Signature Edition Laptop.

When the system starts I am getting a message in the desktop:

```
  InitializeATKCPIDevice retrns false
```

What does this mean? COuld it be a driver that needs to be installed (is missing)?

Answer (score 0):

It's **Asus ATK Package** Error. This driver can be found here: [support.asus.com/Download.aspx?SLanguage=en&m=ATK+Package](http://support.asus.com/Download.aspx?SLanguage=en&m=ATK%20Package)

And, moreover, "ATKCPIDevice" notification informs you what problem is particularly in lack of PCI-bus device driver.
So try to install ATK. If that don't help you, then read below P.S.

P.S. Officially Tehnical Support of Asus tells what ATK should be installed at first to prevent problems with PCI and all the other Device drivers. Afraid, what in this case you should better delete all the other drivers, you have installed, then install ATK-Package at first, and only afterwards reinstall all the other drivers. As it can damage your OS, you probably should to reinstall it. Note, what if you have pre-installed Win8/Win8.1 for your model (suppose, you're for model US01T), you'd better contact Asus Technical Support for help - there is a little bit sofisticated process of reinstalletion.

Btw, brilliant choice of Asus x200ma, I also picked the same, but the black one. =)